# C program running caused problems to laptop

Tags: codeblocks

I tried to run a small program with arrays in C in my laptop (in Codeblocks) and it was supposed to return an error (or at least that was what I was waiting to see). But it run crazy couldn't stop it an since then my laptop functions but the screen is a mess. It is flickering in a certain part all the time and views of open windows stick forever and it goes worse as time goes by. I run diagnostics but there is no problem located. I formatted it and still the same. Is this hardware problem?

Comment: It's extraordinarily unlikely that running a program could cause any permanent problems unless you were deleting system files. It's possible that your computer was already almost broken and a little stress the program caused pushed it over the edge.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just using 100% or either cpu or ram?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. This program was an exercise tying to demonstrate c code that can cause overflow. The moment I run it... everything happened.